# Let B be set of all twice differentialbe function $ f(0)=1, f'(0)=-1$ . .. Find supremum of $ {(f''(0):f\in B})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let B be set of all twice differentiable function $f$ such that  $f: (-1,1) \to (0,\infty)$
and $ f(0)=1, f'(0)=-1$ . 
We have new function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$  and $g(x)$ is convex on interval $(-1,1)$.

Find the supremum of the set $\{ f''(0):f \in B \} $

---

My work:
If function $g(x)$ is convex that means that $g''(x)>0$
$$g'(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}$$
$$g''(x)=\frac{2f'(x)^2-f(x)f''(x)}{f^3(x)}$$
But I don't have idea how to use value of $f$ and $f'$ to get resultat.

Comment: $< \cdot, \cdot >$? Do you mean $( \cdot, \cdot )$ or $[ \cdot, \cdot ]$?

Comment: I have edited your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

After calculating 
$$g^{\prime\prime} (x) = -\frac{f^{\prime\prime} (x)f(x)-2(f^\prime(x))^2}{f(x)^3}$$
By inserting the value for $x=0$ and using $g^{\prime\prime} (x)\ge0$ you arrive, after rearranging at $f^{\prime\prime} (x)\le-2$. You can now try to find $f$ such that value is attained or such that you get at least close to that value. If that works out the $\sup$ is $-2$...